# sendPasswordResetEmail failed: First argument \"email\" must be a valid string.", con Firebase usando React

Tags: reactjs, firebase

estaba haciendo una parte de mi página para restablecer la contraseña, pero por algún motivo me dice que el email que le paso a la función de Firebase no es un string válido. Sinceramente no entiendo a que se refiere y no sé cómo solucionarlo.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Layout from '../Components/Layouts/Layout';
import { TextoSistema } from '../Components/UI/Generales';
import { Espacio, BotonChico } from '../Components/UI/Formularios';
import Router from 'next/router';

import firebase from '../Firebase';

const Password = () => {

  const [ email, guardarEmail ] = useState('');

  const handleChange = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    guardarEmail(e.target.value);
  };
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Layout />
        <h1 className="text-5xl font-bold text-center">¿Contraseña olvidada?</h1>
        <TextoSistema>Con tanto estudiar, es normal que a veces no recordemos algunas cosas... Escribe el correo con el que inicias sesión y te mandaremos la información para que obtengas una nueva contraseña tu contraseña.</TextoSistema>

        <Espacio>
          <label htmlFor="email" className="sr-only">Correo electrónico</label>
          <input 
            type="email"
            placeholder="Correo electrónico"
            value={email}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </Espacio>

        <Espacio>
          <BotonChico
            type="submit"
            value="Enviar"
            onClick={() => {
              firebase.mandarContraseña(guardarEmail);
              Router.push('/passwordMensaje');
            }}
          />
        </Espacio>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Password;
```

Y acá está la función en el archivo de Firebase:

```js
//Restablecimiento de contraseña
    async mandarContraseña(email) {
        return this.auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email)
        .then(() => {
            // Password reset email sent!
            // ..
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            // ..
        });
    }
```

Comment: Independientemente de tu problema, te recomiendo que no uses nombres de variables que lleven letras como la **"ñ"**, como hiciste con la variable `mandarContraseña`. No sé si es tu caso, pero en otros contextos podría darte problemas.